# Second mutable borrow error disapears after introducing a magic line

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

This is my struct (for completeness sake):

```rust
struct Client<'a, T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Unpin
{
    socket: T,
    stage: u8,
    n: usize,
    buf: &'a mut [u8],
}
```

I then implemented a `Future` for the struct, but changed `self` to `me` via `let me = &mut *self;`.
This compiles fine:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Future for Client<'a, T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Unpin
{
    type Output = io::Result<()>;
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {

        let me = &mut *self; // <<<<<<<<<< this fixes it, how?!

        while me.stage == 1 {
            let self_n = me.n;
            let mut rb = ReadBuf::new(&mut me.buf[..self_n]);
            let n = ready!(Pin::new(&mut me.socket).poll_read(cx, &mut rb));
        }
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

however, if I remove that conversion, it will trigger a borrow checker error:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Future for Client<'a, T>
where
    T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + Unpin
{
    type Output = io::Result<()>;
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {

        // magic line removed
        
        while self.stage == 1 {
            let self_n = self.n;
            let mut rb = ReadBuf::new(&mut self.buf[..self_n]);
            let n = ready!(Pin::new(&mut self.socket).poll_read(cx, &mut rb));
        }
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> z.rs:y:x
   |
84 |             let mut rb = ReadBuf::new(&mut self.buf[..RES.len() - self_n]);
   |                                            ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
85 |             let n = ready!(Pin::new(&mut self.socket).poll_read(cx, &mut rb));
   |                                          ^^^^                       ------- first borrow later used here
   |                                          |
   |                                          second mutable borrow occurs here
```

What is it about `let me = &mut *self;` that gets it compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in [this thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63993), mutably borrowing an element of a `Pin` requires using its `DerefMut` implementation, which mutably borrows the entire `Pin`. Thus, you cannot mutably borrow 2 fields, even if they are disjoint. The line `let me = &mut *self` (or alternatively `let me = &mut self`) uses `Pin`'s `DerefMut` implementation to generate a `&mut Self` from the `Pin<&mut Self>`. It only does this once, **then** two disjoint fields are borrowed through **that** mutable borrow, which leads to no errors.